# Convert textfile to dataframe in r

Tags: r

how to convert a text file given in below format

```
ASDDSDAS 111 132  456 
DSSADSDA 1 12335
```

Into a dataframe with

```
circleid nodeid
ASDDSDAS 111
ASDDSDAS 132
ASDDSDAS 456
DSSADSDA 1
DSSADSDA 12335
```

So far

```
 library(tidyverse)
circ <- read_file(circ_file)
cir <- read.csv(text=circ, sep=" ", header = FALSE) %>% 
  separate_rows(circ, convert = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!is.na(circ))

#Error: Unknown column ASDDSDAS.
```

Comment: Please provide data with `dput` or at least something we can copy and paste easily. Why are you reading the data from a file into a character,  rather than just calling `read.csv` directly on the file? What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using base R only.

```
fun <- function(x){
    data.frame(circleid = x[1], nodeid = as.numeric(x[-1]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

uri <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/APS/master/100129275726588145876.circles"
txt <- readLines(uri)
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(txt, "[[:blank:]]+"), fun))

print(head(result), digits = 20)
#     circleid                nodeid
#1 Az1VWXrXzeg 111439704478822924298
#2 Az1VWXrXzeg 102604554618567114752
#3 Az1VWXrXzeg 113609548050074206218
#4 Az1VWXrXzeg 103090889232468295680
#5 Az1VWXrXzeg 108271734388645117952
#6 Az1VWXrXzeg 111566503164646162432
```

Comment: Error in data.frame(circleid = x[1], nodeid = as.numeric(x[-1]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/APS/master/100129275726588145876.circles -- actual file at this location

Comment: @pranavnerurkar Done.

Comment: On my system I get 
Az1VWXrXzeg     1.114397e+20
When i print result as csv    1.114397e+20 is 111439704478822000000

Comment: @pranavnerurkar That is just the `print` command default output digits. The real numbers are the ones in the csv or in my answer above. See my `print` command, argument `digits = 20`.

Answer (score 2):

here is a way using the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
cir <- 
  read_table2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/APS/master/100129275726588145876.circles", col_names = FALSE) %>% 
  rename(circleid = X1) %>% 
  gather(key = "key", value = "nodeid", -circleid) %>% 
  arrange(circleid, nodeid) %>% 
  select(-key)
```

This does generate a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In rbind(names(probs), probs_f) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```